# math software - permutation group elements operation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, math-software

I need a software allows to calculate operation elements of permutation group. For example the following elements operation yields identity permutation
$$ (1234)(1423) = (1)$$

Sage seems to solve the problem. I needed to find conjugacy classes of $D_4$

```
D = DihedralGroup(4)
print D
D.list()
for i in D:
    l = list()
    for j in D:
        l.append(j*i*j^-1)
    print l
```

Comment: In Matlab or Octave you can implement permutations as permutation matrices. But that only works if what you want to permute are numbers. However you can of course always permute vectors of indexes instead and then feed the indexes to what you want to permute.

Comment: GAP, which is freeware.

Comment: Does $D_4$ mean a group of order 8 or order 4 in your question?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov yes it is. The internet however likes to write it as $D_4$

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: thanks, though "yes it is" is ambiguous - better to write explicitly "yes, a group of order 8". You can't refer to "internet" as a credible source here, byt indeed, you can find both types of notations in the mathematical literature. I wrote recently on this at http://blogs.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/alexk/2016/04/17/why-do-we-need-openmath/.

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: I've added new example to the GAP answer below.

Comment: I find it worrying that the internet has opinions on matters of mathematical notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAGE can also do this. It also has a [cloud version](http://cloud.sagemath.com), so you don't have to install anything.

Here's how I would do your example in SAGE:

```
G = SymmetricGroup(4)
G
L = G.list()
g = L[5]
g
h = L[10]
h
g*h

Symmetric group of order 4! as a permutation group
(2,3,4)
(1,2,4,3)
(1,2)
```

To explain what is going on: In the first line I create the symmetric group of order $4!$. Then by typing just "G", SAGE tells me what I've gotten. Then I make a list of all of its elements. I let $g,h$ be element numbers $5$ and $10$, respectively (counting starts at zero). Then I can compute the permutation $gh$.

Comment: exactly I am looking for!!

Answer (score 4):

Try GAP: http://www.gap-system.org . It is designed to work with groups, and specially permutations. Here is a sample:

```
gap> (1,2,3,4)*(1,4,3,2);
()
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(IsPermGroup,8);
Group([ (1,2,3,4), (2,4) ])
gap> cc:=ConjugacyClasses(G);
[ ()^G, (2,4)^G, (1,2)(3,4)^G, (1,2,3,4)^G, (1,3)(2,4)^G ]
gap> for c in cc do
> Print(AsList(c),"\n");
> od;
[ () ]
[ (2,4), (1,3) ]
[ (1,2)(3,4), (1,4)(2,3) ]
[ (1,2,3,4), (1,4,3,2) ]
[ (1,3)(2,4) ]
```